# Adding custom methods to Laravel 5 scheduler

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm wondering what the best way to add things like weekends to the available schedule constraints:

```
Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event.php
public function weekdays()
{
    return $this->spliceIntoPosition(5, '1-5');
}
```

and its logical opposite:

```
public function weekends()
{
        return $this->days(array( '0','6'));
}
```

Where would I include these things so that they're not overwritten with a framework update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if all you are missing is the **weekends()** method, you can achieve that by calling **days(6,7)** on your event.

If you need to add some more logic to the scheduler, please go on reading.

I had a look at the code and while Laravel doesn't offer a way to extend the **Scheduler**, and specifically its scheduled **Events**, with additional methoods, it's still possible to apply additional constraints from your **Kernel::schedule()**.

Depending on your needs, there are 2 ways to do it.

1. If you want to set some custom CRON expression for an event, you can simply use its **cron()** method:

   ```
   protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
   {
       $schedule->call(function () {
           //scheduled code
       })->cron('0 1 2 * * *')->daily();
   }
   ```
2. If you need to apply some CRON constraints using existing methods, but need to modify it later the way **weekdays()** does using **spliceIntoPosition**, you can access it by calling **getExpression()**, modify it, and then set using **cron()**.

   ```
   protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
   {
       $event = $schedule->call(function () {
           //scheduled code
       });

       $scheduledAt = $event->getExpression(); //get cron expression

       ...; //modify the $scheduledAt expression

       $event->cron($scheduledAt); // set the new schedule for that even
   }
   ```

If you want to reuse the logic for multiple events, you can add helper functions in your **Kernel.php**, e.g.:

```
    protected function specialSchedule(\Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event $event) {
      $scheduledAt = $event->getExpression();

      ...; // modify $scheduledAt expression

      $event->cron($scheduledAt);

      return $event;
    }
```

Then you can reuse that logic when defining the schedule:

```
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $this->specialSchedule($schedule->call(function () {
            //scheduled code
        }));
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

There is one more way to do that - a bit more complex, as it requires you to provide your own Schedule and Event classes, but also more flexible.

First, implement your own Event class and add there the new methods:

```
    class CustomEvent extends \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\CallbackEvent {
      public function weekends() {
        return $this->days(6,7);
      }
    }
```

Then your own Schedule class, so that it creates **CustomEvent** objects:

```
    class CustomSchedule extends \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule 
    {
      public function call($callback, array $parameters = [])
      {
        $this->events[] = $event = new CustomEvent($callback, $parameters);

         return $event;
      }

      public function exec($command, array $parameters = [])
      {
        if (count($parameters)) {
          $command .= ' '.$this->compileParameters($parameters);
        }

        $this->events[] = $event = new Event($command);

        return $event;
      }
   }
```

Lastly, in your Kernel.php you need too make sure your new schedule class is used for scheduling:

```
    protected function defineConsoleSchedule()
    {
      $this->app->instance(
        'Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule', $schedule = new Schedule
      );

      $this->schedule($schedule);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm well aware of the built in cron method, I was just wondering where I'd make a ->weekends() method, or specifically for my use: ->holiday(), which would of course be many days that are not always static in a numerical sense, ie. Thanksgiving, or not always on a set day (Dec. 25th). I was hoping to find a way to just call them like the normal ->weekdays() command.

Answer (score 0):

Folowing @jedrzej.kurylo's answer, i did this on laravel 5.8:

`php artisan make:model CustomCallbackEvent`

`php artisan make:model CustomEvent`

`php artisan make:model CustomSchedule`

In CustomCallbackEvent:

```
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\CallbackEvent;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\EventMutex;

class CustomCallbackEvent extends CallbackEvent
{
    public function __construct(EventMutex $mutex, $callback, array $parameters = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($mutex, $callback, $parameters);
    }
}
```

In CustomSchedule:

```
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;

class CustomSchedule extends Schedule
{
    public function call($callback, array $parameters = [])
    {
        $this->events[] = $event = new CustomCallbackEvent(
            $this->eventMutex,
            $callback,
            $parameters
        );

        return $event;
    }

    public function exec($command, array $parameters = [])
    {
        if (count($parameters)) {
            $command .= ' '.$this->compileParameters($parameters);
        }

        $this->events[] = $event = new CustomEvent($this->eventMutex, $command, $this->timezone);

        return $event;
    }
}
```

In CustomEvent:

```
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event;

class CustomEvent extends Event
{
    public function myFunction()
    {
        //your logic here
    }
}
```

In Kernel.php:

```
protected function defineConsoleSchedule()
    {
      $this->app->instance(
        'Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule', $schedule = new CustomSchedule
      );

      $this->schedule($schedule);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event` class uses the `Macroable` trait. It means that you can dynamically add methods to the class without inheriting it.

First of all you have to register it in the boot method:

```php
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Event::macro(
            'weekends',
            function () {
                /** @var Event $this */
                return $this->days([0, 6]);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as any other method:

```php
$schedule->command('do-work')->weekends();
```

For more details about macros see https://asklagbox.com/blog/laravel-macros